# selecting records in a many to many table using SQL Groupby and having

Tags: sql-server, group-by, having

I have the following UserRole table for a many to many relationship between users and roles

```
UserRoleId | UserId | RoleId
------------------------
1          | 1      | A
2          | 1      | B
3          | 1      | C
4          | 2      | A
5          | 3      | B
6          | 3      | C
7          | 4      | C
```

I want to be able to select Users which match the criteria below:
1) have only one role
2) And that role is A

So in table above, only `UserRoleId` 4 should be returned since it satisfies both criteria. Using groupby and having I was able to find userId's that have only one role, but am not able to include the check for the second criteria.

```
select userId, count(userId)
from UserRole
group by userId
having COUNT(userId) = 1
```

How can I accomplish this using `groupby` and `having`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do it

```
SELECT userId
  FROM UserRole
 GROUP BY userId
HAVING COUNT(*) = SUM(CASE WHEN RoleId = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

```
| USERID |
|--------|
|      2 |
```

Here is a **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b9014/7)** demo

Comment: Yes. Thanks, it did help. Still don't understand how this works though.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way:

```
SELECT 
    UserId
FROM UserRole
GROUP BY UserId
HAVING
    SUM(CASE WHEN RoleId = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1
    AND SUM(CASE WHEN RoleId <> 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```